# Obtain input and output from other process C#

Tags: c#, c, .net, process.start

Before start let me say that I already tried to use variant which is described [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output#).

Problem is folowing, I have very simple program in C which is just write to output and read input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int size;

    printf("Enter size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("\n size = %d", size);

    return 0;
}
```

Second program wrote in C#. This program should start from another process first and obtain input and output. But the program is freezed when try to read input. At first call of `Console.Write(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var fName = "test.exe";
        var pci = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = fName,
            Arguments = "/c DIR",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        };

        using (var process = Process.Start(pci))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);

            Console.Write(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("4");
            Console.Write(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());

            process.WaitForExit(1000);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Does anybody know why it freezed? Or where to take a look?

P.S. with asnyc reading problem the same

Comment: The isue is process.WaitForExit(1000);  So you are waiting for the Process to terminate.  Does the application automatically close when finish?  Is application putting a '\n' at the end of each response.  ReadLine() expects a '\n'.

Comment: Write the input *before* trying to read the output.

Comment: Regarding rocess.WaitForExit(1000)

Code even not reach this line. In debugger it stuck on line just after 'Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);'.
ReadLine - it was last version. Before I have used just Read, of cycle as used in Microsoft documentation. Result the same

Comment: 'Write the input before trying to read the output'
Why should be before? As you may see that the first line also contains information which I expect to get.

Comment: As @jdweng already pointed out: ReadLine expects an output *line*, including a newline. `printf("Enter size: ");` does not write a newline.

Comment: @KlausGütter, thank you, but it still not works. I added in C program at the end of each printf linefeed. Still no result

Comment: Sounds like an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11292917/3034273 . Can you update your question where you've added linefeed if that still doesn't work?

Comment: @Xerillio, you are right! was need just add `fflush(stdout);`. Thank you so much